# Where is VirtualBox's virtual hard disks repository?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, import, virtual-disk

A colleague shared a VirtualBox VM with me. When double clicking the VDI file, VirtualBox opens but I get a few errors (the errors were related to incorrect paths and UUIDs in the VBOX file). So I had to RTFM...

I found [Importing a VDI in VirtualBox](https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/entry/importing_a_vdi_in_virtualbox) from Oracle's blog. The blog states:

> First copy your VDI file into VirtualBox's virtual hard disks repository. On Mac OS X it's $HOME/Library/VirtualBox/HardDisks/.

I seem to have VDI's scattered all about, but all under a common root folder of `"VirtualBox VMs"`.  And I don't have a folder `"HardDisks"`. So its not clear to me where the repository is, or where I'm supposed to put the VDI.

Where is VirtualBox's virtual hard disks repository in Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For Microsoft Windows OS, default Storage is in `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\VirtualBox VMs`

Which typically expands out to

`C:\Users\[username]\VirtualBox VMs`

The subfolders will be named with the `Name:` field contents entered in the **Create Virtual Machine** dialog where you're asked to enter Name and OS information.

If you've decided to do a little more orgainization, the Machine Name subfolders will be under the Machine Group subfolder. Full implementation may look like the following:

`C:\Users\[username]\VirtualBox VMs\[vm group]\[vm name]`

The VDI may exist elsewhere if you used the option to **Use an existing virtual hard drive**

It's easy to find where the VDI disks reside by using **File=>Virtual Media Manager**

[image]

Comment: On MacOS, it's `~/VirtualBox\ VMs` (or `'~/VirtualBox VMs'` if quoted).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know there is a virtual disk manager. Always had big pain after renaming some .vdi :))))

Answer (score 5):

At the risk of being scolded for not answering the EXACT question...

On Ubuntu (and other Linux distributions?), the directory is:

```
/home/[USER NAME]/.config/VirtualBox
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open OracleVMVirtualBox.
2. Open file from LeftTop. Head to VirtualMediaManagaer.
3. Move on to properties tab.

Press Cltr+D (in short (for windows))
Here you can view the folder for saving things and size(VirtualMemory).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDsk7.png)